# created bitbucket repo deleted it, created again, git remote push fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket

I am using cloud9 IDE on a rails tutorial app.  I created a repo and then pushed the app to the repo on bitbucket.  I got messed up on the app so decided to start from beginning.  I deleted the repo and worked on the app until it worked.  I created another repo on bitbucket and did all commits and when I did these I got a message saying I was three or five commits ahead of remote.  So when I did a push I got

git push
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

Comment: I guess you didn't remove the `.git` directory on your local drive when you deleted the remote repo? Do you mind losing any history for this app?

Comment: Thats correct I didnt remove the .git directory on the local.  I dont really mind losing any history for this app, its only for learning. I do want to push it up and track it on bitbucket though.   I have a question though, do have a .git directory for each directory I init?

Comment: Every git project has a `.git` directory.

Comment: Ok, so should I delete the .git directory and do another git init?  Then push to the repo on bitbucket?  Can I do that without building the app again?

Comment: Yes, you won't lose the source code.

Comment: So I would have to build the app again?  Sorry you just answered this question.

Comment: Did you try a `git push master` instead of just `git push`? You're pushing to a new repo so the remote probably doesn't have a master branch yet so you might need to create it as you're pushing. Deleting all your history and starting over seems unnecessary...

Comment: tangrs I tried git push master and got this <pre><code> fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.<code><pre>

Comment: In addition I cant rmdir .git Its not working I think because I am using cloud9 IDE.  rmdir -rf is not supported

Comment: how about `rm -rf .git`

Comment: Janse   using cloud9  rm -rf .git    returns -r invalid option.    If I use --ignore-fail-on-non-empty option.  it returns nothing but it doesnt remove .git

Comment: I just tried `rm -rf .git` and it worked on the bash tab in `~/workspace`.

Comment: Are you using cloud9?

Comment: yes cloud9 ide through the browser

Comment: uhg?  its not working for me.

Comment: check the permissions maybe `ls -la` then change them if you have to `chown` or `chmod`. But removing the .git directory effectively resets your project (without touching your source code) then you can start over. I've never tried copying workspaces -- you could try that even.

Comment: the permission is drwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind starting from scratch and losing your app's history.

Create a new repo on Bitbucket.

Next, remove the `.git` directory from your local project.

Then initialize a new git repo locally

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

On Bitbucket you'll see a screen like the one below.

[image]

Now just run the commands as exactly as it instructs

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:your-username/project.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Then everything should be reset without any history.